# ReSharper 2016.1 xUnit test runner does not support Theory

Tags: resharper, xunit, xunit.net, resharper-2016

I'm currently using ReSharper 2016.1.2 with the native xUnit test runner. I was wondering why the `Theories` are not supported and get simply ignored from the test sessions. Moreover, trying to run them singularly has no effect at all.

What is also a bit frustrating is that they get *silently* ignored and not reported in the `Ignored Tests` tab count (in my case >20 tests using theories with both `InlineData` and `MemberData`).

The question is: are theories going to be supported or shall I rewrite my test?

Comment: Not sure if still relevant, but maybe try opening an issue at the gh repo https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit/issues

Comment: @robi-y the github repo was there for the xUnit ReSharper Extensions that was required up until version 9.0. ReSharper 2016 (aka 10) has a built in support for xUnit.

Comment: Have you upgraded to xUnit.net 2.1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theory tests are supported. The method should be highlighted in the editor, and when you run the tests, the results tree will include a node for the method, and then automatically add other nodes, one for each theory row. Once the results are shown in the results window, an individual theory (or a group of them) can be highlighted and run, without having to run all of the theories.

If you're seeing any other behaviour, you should [log an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=), with details about how to reproduce.

Comment: I've re-installed ReSharper and now I'm capable of running the theories and the behavior is the one that you're describing. I really can't say why it was acting like that. Thank you for the answer.